# Angular Platform-Server Respond with custom http status code

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am using SSR Platform-Server with ExpressJS
I want to change the HTTP status code from 200 to 404 for page not found

I create a route object as follow

```
[
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

it is working fine in client side but I don't have any idea to change the status code in NodeJS

I try to throw an error and handle it in ExpressJS

so in NotFoundComponent, in OnInit I throw an error but angular capture the error and again I get status = 200

any idea?

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using @nguniversal/express-engine

you can inject custom providers to your app from [express-engine]
and you can modify rendered result
and you can handle errors

https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/ng-express-engine

but request and response is already injected

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/ng-express-engine/src/main.ts#L66

and request and response are expressjs objects

so you can use it like this:

```
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens'
```

and in your controller or service

```
constructor(.... OtherDependencies....., @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private readonly res: any) { }
```

and somewhere in your code like ngOnInit

```
if(this.res) {
    this.res.status(404)
}
```

and if you want to stop angular

```
return this.res.end();
```

or you can add any other valid ExpressJs res code here

======= UPDATE =======

This topic is old and Angular-Universal changes a lot. but still, this topic is valid with no change

new Angular Universal document for expessjs can be found here
[Angular Express Engine](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/express-engine/README.md)

Comment: Both links invalid.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt original links are expired but the same practice is valid. new documentation link added

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code