# Angular 9 SSR 404 Not Found Page with Status code

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Am using Angular 9 with SSR, Now am trying to fetch the 404 page. Its successfully working with client side. But Status is always coming as 200 Ok. When am tried with Angular ssr also its showing 200 is the status code.
My Angular router is successfully passing to the 404 component But issue is with status code. Please help me out of this friends...

My Router Details -

```
{
path: '404',
loadChildren: () => import('./not-found/not-found.module').then(m => m.NotFoundModule)
},
{
path: 'Home',
loadChildren: () => import('./all-india/all-india.module').then(m => m.AllIndiaModule)
},
{
path: '**',
loadChildren: () => import('./not-found/not-found.module').then(m => m.NotFoundModule)
}
```

My Not Found Component.HTML

```
<h1>404 Not Found</h1>
```

My Not found Component.ts File

```
import { Component, OnInit, Optional, Inject,Injector, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Component({
selector: 'app-not-found',
templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response,@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector,
@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { }

ngOnInit() {
 if(isPlatformServer(this.platformId))//Only executes server side
     {
         const response = this.injector.get(RESPONSE) as Response;
         response.status(404);
     }
}
}
```

My Server.TS File

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {REQUEST, RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

export function app() {
  const compression = require('compression');
  const server = express();
  server.use(compression());
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/angular-httpclient-example/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
      req: req,
      res: res,
      providers: [
          {
              provide: REQUEST, useValue: (req)
          },
          {
              provide: RESPONSE, useValue: (res)
          }
      ]
      });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I Tried so many methods. Nothing is working for the status codes.

Comment: Is the angular app being served through a backend (like the ASP.NET Core `UseSpa` middleware), or is it a separate app?

Comment: @Pieterjan Hi, thanks for your valuable reply. am using the backend of PHP Codeigniter. Connecting the backend through the rest API through the services.

Comment: export class DataService { 
private REST_API_SERVER = 'https://mybackendlink';
  public getlocationlist() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER + '/get_location')
      .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}

Comment: If your angular app is being served through your api, you can simply add a middleware before the spa middleware, evaluate the request url, and if this doesn't match a url from the angular app return the 404 statuscode

Comment: Just like I'm doing [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Startup.cs#L451) and [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L155) (The middleware injects the service and calls this method)

Comment: @Pieterjan Hi, Can you show some Demo for the middleware, because am not familiar with the middleware. is it we have to add in our server.ts file..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241677/discussion-between-abijith-ajayan-and-pieterjan).

Answer (score 3):

Create Server Side Response Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServerSideResponseService {
  private response: Response

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) response: any) {
    this.response = response
  }

  setNotFound(message = 'not found'): this {
    if (this.response) {
      this.response.statusCode = 404
      this.response.statusMessage = message
    }
    return this
  }
}
```

and use it in Not Found Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ssr: ServerResponseService) {
    this.ssr.setNotFound();
  }
}
```

Reference
https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular/commit/015b439a39208da4515eb4d18e4d21640fce1df0

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you for this valuable answer forvever